# Has anyone done any testing with BTRFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm curious about BTRFS. Has anyone out there done any testing (ie. performance, stability, etc.) with it? I'd like to know what your results/opinion is, how close is it to production ready?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

As of June, even the creator did not feel it was production ready yet ( [source](https://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/blog-entry/a-conversation-with-chris-mason-btrfs-next-generation-file-system-linux) ).

**Be Conservative when it comes to File Systems:**
Myself, there is nothing I can think of that I would be more conservative with than a file system.  Also, due to the nature of file systems, there can be little bugs that can take months to find, and creep up rarely.  But when they do, it can take everything down if you use it on the root partition.

Comment: "there can be little bugs that can take months to find"

If not _years_, I agree completely with Kyle on this one. A filesystem is one piece of your system that you should _not_ go bleeding edge with. Heck, I am even a little weary of ext4 being the default in the next Ubuntu release and it was supposed to be 'production ready' quite a while ago...

Answer (score 1):

I've played with it a bit in a sandbox.  Since I have a lot of dubugging tuned on and am doing this in a virtual machine I can't speak for the performance.  It is quite fun to play with and I haven't had any show stoppers from my last build but I don't think it is quite there yet.

As far as file systems go be vary paranoid and conservative.  Unless you have a compelling reason never trust an experimental file system with the canonical copy of your data.

That said, play with it, just don't expect it to answer prayers, feed your dog, or improve your relationships with others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's about ten years from being production ready; that's roughly how long it took ext* to get there, after all.

More seriously, even if it works fairly reliably at the moment -- which it does, mostly -- there are years of work left in making a fsck for it that can actually repair problems (the current one can't yet), and in creating userspace tools for managing it that are comparable to the ZFS counterparts.  No-one should be in a hurry to deploy btrfs.